# Ensure a django model field is written only once ? Atomicity guaranteed without locks

Tags: python, django, celery, atomic

I am looking for a reliable way to ensure that for a given instance of a django model, a specific field is written only once.

The code should run in both views or tasks using celery or even rq.

I am thinking about using the following snippet :

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.utils.timezone import now

...

def perform_writeonce(object_pk):
    with transaction.atomic():
        instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=object_pk)

        if instance.value is None:
            instance.value = 'Value written now : {}'.format(now())
            instance.save()
```

The objective is that value should only be written once and only if its value is None.

Are you confident in this snippet or is there something I missed ?

I am using multiple gunicorn instances and celery workers with a single postgresql database server.

I am trying to avoid locks at all costs, so any solution with application-land locks are no good.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i am confident. because transaction depends on db layer not application layer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a reliable way to ensure that for any given instance of a django model, a specific field is written only once.
>
> The expected behavior is like the auto_now_add option to datefields.

`auto_now_add` does not ensure that a field is written only once. You can still write to that field if you really want to. It just doesn't show up by default in admin forms etc.

You can do the same for other fields by setting `Field.editable`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#editable

> **Field.editable**
>
> If `False`, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other
> `ModelForm`. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is
> `True`.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I am not looking to replicate the behavior of auto_now_add nor the editable attribute. The issue is linked to concurrency and concurrent access to the database using transactions. Thanks anyway

Comment: Then you should give a clear explanation of the expected behavior in your question. If you want to write to a field just once, that time should be when the instance is first saved to the the database. If concurrency is a problem, the model code might not be the right place to solve it. Why not use a task queue and let celery do all updates to this particular model?